# how to get multiple products from cart to paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce

I want to get multiple products on paypal payment page. I am only getting a single first product at the moment. can someone help me out where I am wrong. below is my code..i searched google and found two more things to be changed. i.e. _xclick to _cart and one more `<input type='hidden' value='1' name='upload'/>`

Now I am getting your cart is empty.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temporderdetails WHERE omid = '$ordermaster_id' " ) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

    $productid  = $row['productid'];
    $quantity   = $row['qty'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $subtotal = $row['subtotal'];


    $query1 = mysql_query("select product_name from products where product_id = '$productid'" ) or die(mysql_error());


    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){

    $product = $row1['product_name'];


        <form action='<?php echo $payment_url ;?>' method='post'>
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">

            <input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $payment_email;?>'>

            <input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='<?php echo $product;?>'>

            <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1'>

            <input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='<?php echo $quantity; ?>'>

            <input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $grandtotal;?>'>

            <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>

            <input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo $payment_success;?>'>

            <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo $payment_failed;?>'>


}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of multiple products you have to use the following variables for each product:
amount_x
item_name_x

where x is the product number (starting from 1). So, what you have to do is something like this:

```
<form action='<?php echo $payment_url ;?>' method='post'>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $payment_email;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='upload' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='<?php echo $payment_success;?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='<?php echo $payment_failed;?>'>
```

In here you can get all your products (your "while" statement), use a counter variable, and then:

```
    <input type='hidden' name='amount_<?php echo $counter;?>' value='<?php $price ?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='item_name_<?php echo $counter;?>' value='<?php echo $product?>'>
    <?php $counter++ ?>
```

Finally close the form

```
</form>
```